# Alternative to WHERE on alias

Tags: mysql, sql

The logic is pretty simple, I have first, last name columns and I wish to concatenate them and make a search based on the concatenated column fullName.

My query does not work since I cannot do where on a alias:

```
SELECT CONCAT(profile_firstname, ' ', profile_lastname) AS fullName FROM Profiles WHERE fullName = '%a%';
```

What would be the alternative is acquiring a similar result?

Comment: An outer query where `fullname` exists can do  `where fullname=...`

Comment: He has just said the alias created from concatenation does not allow him to use it in a WHERE criteria. I would suggest add your concatenation to the where clause too **WHERE CONCAT(profile_firstname, ' ', profile_lastname) = '%a%'**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `having` clause, for example (*in your specific case*):

```
having fullName = '%a%';
```

Comment: Thanks, however, I get an empty result set when I chain it at the end of my query instead of where. Am I doing it right?

Comment: Yes, you should use it instead of where

Comment: `HAVING` is for aggregated values, although it is allowed without `GROUP BY` it doesn't make sense to replace `WHERE` by it.

Comment: @DanFromGermany: `having` without `group by` works like a `where` clause, but it is executed after `select` (as opposite to `where`) so aliases are available.

Comment: @potashin I didn't read the question carefully enough, there is no functional benefit tho you are right!

Comment: I was writing = instead of like, I am sorry :)

Answer (score 4):

This may be more what you're looking for......

```
SELECT Sub_Query.* 
FROM 
(
  SELECT CONCAT(profile_firstname, ' ', profile_lastname) AS fullName FROM Profiles
) Sub_Query
WHERE 
  Sub_Query.fullName = '%a%';
```

But you might want to consider a View which would have fullName and run your queries against that......which is essentially what's going on in this.

Answer (score 3):

This will work:

```
SELECT CONCAT(profile_firstname, ' ', profile_lastname) AS fullName
FROM Profiles
WHERE CONCAT(profile_firstname, ' ', profile_lastname) = '%a%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use below:

SELECT (profile_firstname + ' ' +  profile_lastname) AS fullName FROM Profiles 
WHERE (profile_firstname + ' ' +  profile_lastname) LIKE '%a%'

Comment: Appreciate the alternative, but I am fan of using HAVING, it is a direct replacement of WHERE and seems to help keeping the query tidier :)